# WebSocket not working over the Internet

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ip, websocket

I currently have a `WebSocket` server (C#) and a client (JavaScript / HTML5). This works great on my local network, however when I listen to and make the client connect to my 'real' IP (which is the IP of my router identifiable worldwide, i.e. instead of `192.168.x.x`), it doesn't work. The WebSocket class does get a `readyState` of `1`, but when I send anything from the client to the server (or the other way round), the message doesn't arrive.

I already set my router to enable port forwarding, otherwise it wouldn't work anyway (I tried not enabling this and the `WebSocket` immediately got a `readyState` of `2`).

JavaScript code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://some.real.ip.address:myport");
// For privacy reasons I'd like to keep the address and port private
```

C# code (I'm using the Nugget library to implement a socket server):

```
var nugget = new WebSocketServer(myport, "*", "ws://some.real.ip.address:myport");
```

Obviously, the address and port are the same.

What could be the cause of it? Is it possible that my ISP doesn't allow socket connections when my computer is the server? If so, how come the `WebSocket` does get a `readyState` of `1`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you test the router forwarding rules in another way?
Just open a telnet connection and check for communication or temporarily host a simple web server to see if the ports are opened correctly.

Comment: This does work - forwarding incoming requests on some port to my web server port works like a charm. But the web socket port fails weirdly... Also, when accessing my web socket port as a HTTP request through Chrome, I get an empty response error, whilst using other ports results in connection refuse errors. So there is a difference, i.e. port forwarding is not the point I guess.

Comment: Oops - my fault! I forgot to add a path to the `WebSocket` address. I needed to add `/bke` after the IP in JavaScript, as I'm restricting listening to that path. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault - not sure if this answer will help anybody, but I'm listening to `/bke` specifically, and I did not pass this in the JavaScript `WebSocket` constructor...